# Updating a Google Spreadsheet using C#

Tags: c#

This is my first time posting on here, I am new to working with the Google API.  The issue I am having is I am trying to log into my Google Drive account and update specific cells in the spreadsheet.  I am able to log into my Google Drive but when I try to access the Google Spreadsheet I am getting a "Parsing Failed" error.

```
using System;
using Google;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;

UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets
            {ClientId = "XXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com",ClientSecret = "XXXXX", }, new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }, "user", CancellationToken.None).Result;


        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
        });

SpreadsheetsService services = new SpreadsheetsService("site");
SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
SpreadsheetFeed feed = services.Query(query);`
```

When I reach the services.Query(query) I am getting the parsing failed error.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full error

```
Google.GData.Client.ClientFeedException was unhandled
 HResult=-2146233088
 Message=Parsing failed
 Source=Google.GData.Client
 StackTrace:
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.Parse(Stream streamInput, AtomFeed feed)
   at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeed.Parse(Stream stream, AlternativeFormat format)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.CreateAndParseFeed(Stream inputStream, Uri uriToUse)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Query(FeedQuery feedQuery)
   at Google.GData.Spreadsheets.SpreadsheetsService.Query(SpreadsheetQuery feedQuery)
   at webPull.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\shartnett\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\webPull\webPull\Program.cs:line 80
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
 InnerException: System.Xml.XmlException
   HResult=-2146232000
   Message=Root element is missing.
   Source=System.Xml
   LineNumber=0
   LinePosition=0
   SourceUri=""
   StackTrace:
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
        at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()
        at Google.GData.Client.BaseFeedParser.MoveToStartElement(XmlReader reader)
        at Google.GData.Client.AtomFeedParser.Parse(Stream streamInput, AtomFeed feed)
   InnerException:
```

Comment: can you post the full error with stack trace?

Comment: I have the same error (Failed Parsing). You could solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19153860/access-google-public-spreadsheet-using-c-sharp-and-google-data-api) that discusses the "parsing failed" issue.

It mentions seeing a failed call in Fiddler to http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd.

Try using Fiddler and see what calls might be failing.

Comment: Did you see what is going across the wire with Fiddler or WireShark?